# set selected object from selectOneMenu to inputText in jsf

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have problem with jsf. My jsf code is:

```
 <h:form>
         <p:selectOneMenu style="text-align:left;"
         value="#{contractBean.selectedCust}" converter="CustomerConverter">
         <f:selectItems value="#{classificatorBean.customerList}"
         var="customer" itemLabel="#{customer.name} #{customer.sname}" itemValue="#{customer}" />

          <p:ajax event="change"   update="custTel" />

          </p:selectOneMenu>
          <p:inputText  id="custTel" value="#{contractBean.selectedCust.name}  " />
 </h:form>
```

and I have managed bean (Contractbean) with getter and setter functions  of selectedCust Customer object. My problem is when menu changed object don`t show customer`s tel number.

Comment: What about your converter? Seems like you should look there for possible errors.

Comment: Post your converter and backbean code please.

Answer (score 0):

try to use ajax like this:
    `<p:ajax event="change" process="@this"  update="custTel" />`

Comment: Thanks a lot.  The  error  was  in my converter as you said.  I resolved problem.